# Help with plotting coxme data

Tags: r, data-visualization, cox-model

I've run a mixed effects cox model using coxme in R. I can find code online regarding how to plot regular cox proportional hazards data but nothing about coxme. I am receiving error messages if I try to use the same code.

The code for my model is as follows:

```
model = coxme(Surv(Time, Status) ~ Condition + Distance + PP + (1|ID), data=data)
```

I am mainly interested in the effect of Condition, which contains two levels. Each subject (ID) took part in both levels of Condition. I would thus like to produce a plot with two survival curves, one for each Condition.